# how can Implement widget in flutter

Tags: flutter

I want to ask how can implement this [[image: widget in example image]] in flutter.

I have new project and want to implement this feature in project.

I don't know the widget name to search for it.

Please Can anyone help me what widget name to search for it,

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/KkkhC.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Slider](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Slider-class.html) Widget helps you to do that

example :

```
Slider(
          value: _currentSliderValue,
          min: 0,
          max: 100,
          divisions: 100,
          label: _currentSliderValue.round().toString(),
          onChanged: (double value) {
            setState(() {
              _currentSliderValue = value;
            });
          },
        )
```

Output :

[image]